# Get raw video from gif to mp4 conversion

Tags: php, wordpress

I am in need of converting user uploaded gif files to mp4 format in php. Is this possible and if so, how?

The only current solution I have found is by uploading it to an api which would then provide me with a temporary link that I could use. That, however, would be a very bad solution because I would then have to crawl the link to obtain the raw video code. This is necessary as I am later uploading it to a WordPress media library.

Comment: Search `ffmpeg gif to mp4`.

Comment: Is it possible in pure php? **No.** Others have mentioned installing ffmpeg on your server and using it. That's the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: not possible in pure php but is by installing and using ffmpeg on your server.